# Installing .ipa file on unregistered iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I am having a confusion, If we have the .ipa file of xcode project, to be installed on any iPhones which are not registered on my Member Center, then can I install it on that iPhone or not? I have Developer Program enrolled ($99/year).

Also one more question, if we have the Enterprise program enrolled, and we create the .ipa file and install it on iPhone, does that iPhone need to be registered on Enterprise program?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

An `ipa` signed with a developer certificate or `Ad-Hoc` distribution cert may only be installed on the specific devices listed on that certificate. Ones which you have added on the portal prior to generating the cert.

An `ipa` signed with an Enterprise cert may be installed on **any** iDevice. The device does not have to be registered on the portal. You do have a legal obligation to adhere to the rules of the enterprise program however.

Comment: With XCode 5+, the "generating the cert" part is automated by XCode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Warren. What if I use Distribution certificate and Distribution provisioning profile, do I still need to register my device in which I want to install .ipa file?

Comment: True. But in the event you can't get to `developer.apple.com` you're going to be stuck with an existing device manifest.

Comment: Distribution profile is only of use to you when handing the package to the app store.

Comment: @Dream. Ad-Hoc "Distribution" provisioning profile still has the devices listed in it. You can't get around adding the devices unless you have Enterprise.

Comment: ok thank you Warren and Marcus for your answer.I think enrolling the Enterprise program is the solution for me then.